# An inherited autowired field is not initialized by the time the constructor code is executed. Why, and how do I resolve this?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, dependency-injection

A parent has an autowired field. I try to use it in a child constructor to initialize that child's field and get an NPE: the parent field, in the code below it's `testUtil`, is not yet initialized. Can you please explain it? I'm also interested in how I avoid this exception. As I understand it, all the fields of the parent class should somehow be autowired and initialized before any code in the child constructor is executed, but for some reason they aren't

```java
public class UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest extends IntegrationTestContext {
    private static final String testUsername = "mickey_m";
    private static final String testPassword = "mickey";
    private final String token;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "/api/v1/user/question-comments/";
    private static final String BASE_SCRIPT_PATH = "/sql/UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest/";
    private ExpectationTester expectationTester;

    public UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest() throws Exception {
        /* If I understand correctly, here we should have an implicit super() call
     and then some reflexion magic to initialize the parent fields. But 
    that initialization doesn't happen! */
        token = testUtil.getToken(testUsername, testPassword); // ← the field in question
    }
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Testcontainers
public class IntegrationTestContext {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Autowired
    protected TestUtil testUtil; // ← it's autowired
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class TestUtil {
    // the entire purpose of this class is to retrieve a JWT token
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final MockMvc mockMvc;

    public String getToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/token")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new JwtRequestDto(username, password))))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
        ObjectNode content = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), ObjectNode.class);
        return "Bearer " + objectMapper.readValue(content.get("data").toString(), String.class);
    }
}
```

**How do I make use of an inherited autowired field in a child constructor?**

Comment: Autowired fields are always wired after the constructor has been completed. Why? Because you need an instance to set the fields and the instance is only available after the constructor has run. Switch to constructor-based injection: https://odrotbohm.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/

Comment: @knittl but isn't it completed? The moment JVM starts executing child constructor code, the super construction is already over and done with, isn't it?

Comment: There is no "child object" and "parent object". The sequence of actions is: 1) create instance of child class (this will call the parent ctor and the child ctor) 2) call setters/set fields by reflection for autowired fields. There's no point between 1) and 2) where Spring could work its magic; Spring needs a fully constructed object to set fields (the JVM doesn't give you access to partially constructed objects, except from inside the constructor itself)

Comment: @knittl when `super()` is implicitly called, isn't an associated parent object created? If so, aren't its fields then autowired?

Comment: @knittl ChatGPT says, *"When you create an instance of a child class in Java, by default, **an instance of the parent class is also created**. This happens because the child class constructor implicitly calls the parent class constructor using the super() statement as the first line of the child class constructor."*

Comment: ChatGPT is a text generator which generates text that reads nicely. I hate to break it to you, but it often generates bu*****it. There is only one instance/object; there is no parent instance + child instance. Yes, the parent _class_ constructor is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because field injection only happen after the test class is instantiated . So you would find `TestUtil` is not injected yet when the test class 's constructor is executing.

You can use the constructor injection to solve it :

```java
public class UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest extends IntegrationTestContext {

     @Autowired
     public UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest(TestUtil testUtil) throws Exception {
       super(testUtil);
       token = testUtil.getToken(testUsername, testPassword);
     }

}

public class IntegrationTestContext {

    public IntegrationTestContext(TestUtil testUtil){
       this.testUtil = testUtil;
    }
}
```

Or a more natural way for testing is keep using the field injection but use `@BeforeEach` to configure the token :

```java
public class UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest extends IntegrationTestContext {

    private String token;
   

   //no more constructor 

   @BeforeEach
   void beforeEach(){
      this.token = testUtil.getToken(testUsername, testPassword); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But doesn't `TestUtil` belong to the parent whose constructor has already been implicitly executed by the time `token` is initialized?

Comment: yes. but when it execute the parent 's constructor , `TestUtil` is still not injected yet. The order of the execution should be :  parent constructor execute --> children constructor executes --> inject the `TestUtil` children instance. Also if you just new the children , it will only create the children instance , but not create a parent instance.

Comment: Got it. Also, why did you explicitly autowire the test class's only constructor?

Comment: Wait. ChatGPT says, *"When you create an instance of a child class in Java, by default, **an instance of the parent class is also created**. This happens because the child class constructor implicitly calls the parent class constructor using the super() statement as the first line of the child class constructor."*

Comment: @Sergey ChatGPT is wrong. It generates text that sounds plausible and in this case is plainly wrong

Comment: @knittl ha! I remember I asked it to provide some peer-reviewed papers on the effect of paid vacation leave on productivity, and it so confidently produced five or so. I then began to check them on Google Scholar, and it appears it made all of them up, pulled them out of its ass. Sounded so plausible, though: it included authors, dates of publication, summaries...

Comment: Do you think your code can be simplified to `@Autowired
     public UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest(TestUtil testUtil) throws Exception {
       token = testUtil.getToken(testUsername, testPassword);
     }`? Why initialize it with the `super()` constructor if I can directly use the autowired constructor argument?